# Multiple dropdowns, onChange and useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, onchange

First I want to apologize for my English as it's not my first language. Hope this explanation will not be too obscure.

When I don't use useEffect, all items are displayed from the outset/array is mapped. When I choose an option first time, nothing happens, but the second time I filter, it works.

However, when I use useEffect, having handlePriceChange(event) in it, and "priceValue" as a dependency, list of all items is not displayed from the beginning/the section is empty, yet array is filtered at the first attempt, showing corresponding results.

I basically want all items to be displayed from the beginning and then filtered. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
 import data from "./data";

 const SearchBar = () => {

   const [houses, setHouses] = useState(data);
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
   const [priceValue, setPriceValue] = useState("");

   const handlePriceChange = (event) => 
   {
    setPriceValue(event.target.value);
    const newArray = data.filter((house) => house.price === priceValue);
    setHouses(newArray);
   };

   useEffect(() => {
      handlePriceChange(event);
   }, [priceValue]);


   return (
    <>
        <div className="search-bar" id="search">

        <label className="price-label">
          Price
          <select
            value={priceValue}
            onChange={handlePriceChange}
            className="dropdown-menu"
          >
            <option value="select">Select</option>
            <option value="$250-350K">$250-350K</option>
            <option value="$350-550K">$350-550K</option>
            <option value="$550-750K">$550-750K</option>
          </select>
        </label>
       
      </div>
     <div className="lower-section" id="houses">
        {houses.map((house) => {
          const { id, pictureURL, info, location, price } = house;
          return (
            <div key={id} className="house-div">
              <img src={pictureURL} alt="house" />
              <button className="btn-more">Show details</button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default SearchBar; 
`
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens like that because you filter the list but don't have a matching value at the beginning (it is an empty string), so the filter method returns an empty array.

In the `handlePriceChange` function, you can add check if priceValue is empty.

```js
const handlePriceChange = (event) => {
    if (!priceValue) {
      return;
    }

    setPriceValue(event.target.value);
    const newArray = data.filter((house) => house.price === priceValue);
    setHouses(newArray);
   };
```

Also, it still will not work, if I am not mistaken.
You should have 2 functions.

- One for handling `priceValue` change - handlePriceChange, fired on onChange in select,
- And one that set a new array with `houses`. This function should fire on `useEfect` with priceValue as the dependency.

```js
   const [houses, setHouses] = useState(data);
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
   const [priceValue, setPriceValue] = useState("");

   const handlePriceChange = (event) => {
     setPriceValue(event.target.value);
   };

   const filterArray = () => {
     if (!priceValue) {
       return;
     }

     const newArray = data.filter((house) => house.price === priceValue);

     setHouses(newArray);
   };

   useEffect(() => {
      filterArray();
   }, [priceValue]);
```